# trying to check if another session with same session.username exists

Tags: node.js

I am currently practicing nodeJS and I would like to achieve something like this :

I am trying to check if another session with the same session.username exists. and if it does, display a warning. I am doing it this way :

```
app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
  let options = {"username": req.body.username, "error": null};
  if(!req.body.username) {
    options.error = "username required nobi";
    res.render('login', options);
  } else if (req.body.username == req.session.username) {
    res.redirect('/');
  } else {
    req.sessionStore.all( (err, sessions) => {
      if(!err) {
        let isUsed = false;
        let i=0;
        for(i; i < sessions.length; i++) {
          let session = JSON.parse(sessions[i]);
          if (session.username == req.body.username) {
            err = "name already taken";
            isUsed = true;
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      if (err) {
        options.error = err;
        res.render('login', options);
      } else {
        req.session.username = req.body.username;
        res.redirect("/");
      }
    });
  }
});
```

It is not working : I am connecting on chrome and IE with the same username. I do not want that to be possible

as an illustration (if needed) :

```
{ If9a9SgOoq7roW8Za84CouSEzgqDs1Q3:
   { cookie: { originalMaxAge: null, expires: null, httpOnly: true, path: '/' },
     username: 'pseudo' },
  MBs41iJmoQpLLCDhP8aFAk5PWAZ_ZQSV:
   { cookie: { originalMaxAge: null, expires: null, httpOnly: true, path: '/' },
     username: 'pseudo' } }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    // You can store username in res.locals.username after auth
    // It's not necessary to pass it into render.

    let username = req.body.username;
    if(!username) 
        return res.render('login', {error: 'username required nobi'});

    if (username == req.session.username) 
        return res.redirect('/');

    if (username && username != req.session.username)   
        return ... // maybe destroy current session?

    req.sessionStore.all( (err, sessions) => {
        if (err) 
            return res.render('login', {error: err.message});

        let isUsed = Object.keys(sessions).some((id) => sessions[id].username == username);
        if (isUsed)
            return res.render('login', {error: 'Already used'});

        req.session.username = username;
        res.locals.username = username;
        res.redirect('/');
    });
});
```

Comment: would you mind to explain -> 

let isUsed = Object.keys(sessions).some((s) => s.username == username);

Thank you for helping me :)

Comment: Oops, it'a a bug. I fixed it. `Object.keys` returns all ids. Method `some` checks all array elements by condition.

Comment: Ok I understand :) Thank you!

Comment: Hm sorry, don't know whats happening, trying to launch it and the page is loading, nothing more D: